# How to convert this SQL query into Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

So I have a SQL Query with:

```
select min(date_part('year', "date"))
from "Arts" a
```

I want to write it on sequelize query, can someone help me?

```
Art.findOne({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn('MAX'), sequelize.fn("date_part",'year',sequelize.col('dateField'))]]
})
```

Comment: Why do you have `sequelize.fn('MAX')`, if you are looking for `min` in the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you are looking for MIN and based on [the documentation](https://sequelize.org/):

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

Art.findOne({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.fn('min', sequelize.fn('date_part', 'year', sequelize.col('date'))), 'minYear']
  ]
});
```

`Art` is the model representing your "Arts" table, and `date` is the field representing the "date" column

The `attributes` option specifies the columns or functions you want to select. In your case, you need to use `sequelize.fn` to define the `date_part` function with the `'year'` parameter and apply it to the `date` column.